# Shortcuts in xcode to switch between project navigator, main file, etc

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any keyboard shortcut to switch to the project navigator, select a file and then edit the file? I use shortcuts for switching between tabs etc and I find it troublesome to use the mouse to choose a new file in the project navigator and then click the main area again to start editing it..
Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I hope I understand what you're asking:

> **Command** - **Option** - **~** (*Tilde*)

This will navigate through areas you have open in Xcode. If you only have the project view and editor open, this should bounce between the two.

Comment: Hmm this is not working for me..have overridden the keybinding with something else? A ` is just being printed even if i press option and tilde together..

Comment: Try holding **Command** and **Option** together and then hitting **~**. If you look in the keybindings, it's labeled `Move Focus To Next Area`
  
Hope that helps :)

Comment: I just found out that pressing CMD + J gives an awesome way to switch focus between open areas!

Comment: If you happen to use the XVim plugin it seems to prevent the Command - Option - ~ shortcut from moving focus OUT of the editor to another area of the IDE.

Comment: Command - ~ (Tilde)   (without Option button) works fine

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is: ⌘~ (Command + Tilde)

Comment: You meant ⌘~ (Command + Tilde)

Answer (score 0):

For the default key-bindings in Xcode 14...

To go to the project navigator (menu item View / Navigators / Project), use ⌘1 (command-1).

To go to the code editor (menu item Navigate / Move Focus to Next Editor), use  ^` (control-backtick).

You can also cycle through the project navigator, code editor, and Inspectors area with ⌥⌘` (option-command-backtick).

If you have the Assistant code editor open, these all seem to behave a little unpredictably.